# Get table name from another table using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I need to delete records based on an ID column.  We have implemented referential integrity in the database using foreign keys.  The hierarchy has been identified and the order for deleting all the child table data before the parent table data is indicated in a foreign key table like so:

```
id tablename
10 childtable1
 9 childtable2
 8 childtable3
 7 childtable4
 6 childtable5
 5 childtable6
 4 childtable7
 3 childtable8
 2 childtable9
 1 childtable10
 0 parenttable
```

The query to delete the data is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0            
DELETE TOP (100000) FROM mytable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.myIDtable 
    WHERE myIDtable.ID = mytable.ID
        AND myIDtable.ID IN (1,2)
)
SET @i=@i+1
COMMIT;
```

The problem is that I need to pass the table name to the delete statement  based on the value of the ID column the foreign key table listed above.

How can I accomplish this?

We are using azure sql database which does not allow cross database querying without creating external tables for every table involved.  We have 150+ tables so that is not an option.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0            
DELETE TOP (100000) FROM mytable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.myIDtable 
    WHERE myIDtable.ID = mytable.ID
        AND myIDtable.ID IN (1,2)
) AND mytable = (select case id
when 10 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 60, 50)))
when 9 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 55, 50)))
when 8 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 49, 50)))
when 7 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 43, 50)))
when 6 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 37, 50)))                          when 5 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 31, 50)))
when 4 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 25, 50)))
when 3 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 19, 50)))
when 2 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 13, 50)))
when 1 then RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TABLENAME, 7, 50)))
else tablename
end       
from dbo.foreignkeytable)
SET @i=@i+1
COMMIT;
```

Comment: The question i far way to be clear. Can't you simplify what do you exactly want?

Comment: I am trying to delete data in all tables having a given id.  Because of foreign key constraints, I need to delete the data in the child tables before I can delete them in the parent table.  I created a table to identify the foreign key hierarchy.  In that table I have an ID column indicating the tree level of the child table and the parent table.  Base on the ID column in the foreign key table, I would like to pass the table name to the delete query.  Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Comment: The only way to pass a table name as variable to a query is using dynamic sql. If you search for it you'll find many examples. I hope this is not a recurring operation. I'm not 100% but I think azure allows dynamic sql.

Comment: You could also use `on delete cascade`

Comment: Thank you HoneyBadger.  Delete cascade is not an option.  Dynamic sql is the only way I see forward.  I was hoping there was a way I hadn't thought of.  But it does seem that the only way is with dynamic sql.